# Android broadcast between class and activity

Tags: android, broadcast

my receiver is not working. The probllem is between a class and activity. im traying to send message from the class to the activity but is not working...
The class is going to comunicate with two activies, one at a time...

My Broadcast code (inside the activity):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

BroadcastReceiver receiver;
IntentFilter filter;

private void init() {
        try {

            ...

            receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    String action = intent.getAction();

                    if(action.equals("HAS_CONECT")){
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IS CONECTED!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else if(action.equals("ARRIVES")){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HAS ARRIVE!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

            };

            filter = new IntentFilter("HAS_CONECT");
            registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
            filter = new IntentFilter("ARRIVES");
            registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

...
}
```

And my code class:

```
public void adviseActivity(){
    try {
        Intent i = new Intent("MESSAGE");
        i.putExtra("msg", "DATA ARRIVE");
        i.setAction("ARRIVES");
        context.sendBroadcast(i);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `onReceive` method, you are looking for the wrong action. The action you had set was `MESSAGE` but the actions you are looking for `onReceive` is `HAS_CONECT` and `ARRIVES`.
Corrected code below:

```
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();

                if(action.equals("MESSAGE")){
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IS CONECTED!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
```

Comment: THANKS! I thought it was the setAction("ARRIVE"); setAction what is the functionilty?

How i get the i.putExtrA("msg","A")?

Comment: `Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); bundle.getString("msg");`

Comment: thanks, now i have a last problem. I have like 5 activities and I have to replicate the broadcast in every activity... i dont know if this was the best solution for comunicate a class and a activitie

Comment: Can you post another question? Need more details